# Android: i want to change color of my Image View

Tags: android, imageview

i want to change color of my imageView.
pasted the code below:-

firstly i pasted the footer.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="#f1eeee"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/fHome"
        android:background="@drawable/colorchanged"
        android:src="@drawable/home" />  <!-- your image here -->

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/fAttendence"
        android:src="@drawable/att" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/fTarget"
        android:src="@drawable/target" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/fReport"
        android:src="@drawable/report" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[pasted .png which i used in this file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxR4L.png)

[pasted .png which i used in this file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFkPe.png)

when i clicked on the imageView i want to set Blue color on it.

can anyone help me for this?

Comment: primary opinion based question .search on google

Comment: @intellij amiya i tried it too but it is not giving me the output as i want.

Comment: Well the best way is to take those 2 .png edit them through photoshop and make them blue, after that save them as "home_selected" for example. Import them to your project, and on click change the icon with imageView.setImageResource(R.Drawable.name_of_image); So for each image that can be selected you have image.png and image_selected.png

Comment: @SachinSolanki see above comment .

Comment: @Tony can you please explain me with the sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `ColorFilter` like below to be triggered on view click:

```
yourImageView.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Note that this will actually change the state of `yourImageView` instance so, you'll need a variable to keep track of that.

Comment: this is working
i have one more question: firstly i used this images as an menu.
If i am jumping to the next page then it remains blue only but i want to set the default gray color when i am jumping to the next page

Comment: You can call `yourImageView.clearColorFilter()` to remove the filter but the logic to handle this need to be written (thats why I said you need a variable to store the state)

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this is to edit through photoshop those two .png.
The currently "grey" versions could have for example the name

> home_button_unselected.png

Edit this image and change from grey to blue or the color you want, save it as

> home_button_selected.png

Import them to your project, so now you have those two files. (for each image)

1) Set the default state, i guess that could be "home_button_unselected.png" through xml like this :

```
   <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/fHome"
        android:src="@drawable/home_button_unselected" />
```

Also in an image view you shouldn't have android:background and android:src working together. If you want to know the difference between those two you could google it.

2) Then in your .java file let's say MainActivity.java you have to put an on click listener to that button, that means make it do something when the user clicks.

- Declare your button(ImageView) as global variable ( before onCreate() )

> private ImageView mHomeButton;

- Find the View (in your onCreate() )

> mHomeButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fHome);

fHome is the id of the imageView if you look at the xml above -> "android:id="@+id/fHome"

- Set the OnClickListener so when user presses the button the image it changes from "home_button_unselected" to "home_button_selected". (inside onCreate() )

.

```
mHomeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     mHomeButton.setImageResource(R.Drawable.home_button_selected); // setting the image to the selected one ( which is blue/selected)
    }
});
```

If you have other buttons you should check first which is selected and if another button is selected, then all other buttons should change to the unselected png

Comment: can we use Selector on this?